# How to automatically fill other form fields after one field is filled?

Tags: php, forms, moodle

I'm creating a form in moodle using moodleform class. I have many fields in the form. What I'm wanting to do is when the user fills in the first field, I want to get the data that he/she entered, search the relevant DB table for a field that matches that input, then populate the other fields for that record.

Please note that the user hasn't pressed any submit button yet. I've been trying to find a function that gets the entered data but all efforts have been in vain. What I found was a get_data() method but I don't even know how to use that correctly. I've been reading the moodle docs but nothing is helping. I'm not a beginner to coding but neither am I an expert.

Here's a code snippet:

```
class requestcourse_form extends moodleform
{
    function definition() 
    {   
    global $CFG, $currentsess, $DB, $USER, $currentrecord; 

    $mform =& $this->_form; // Don't forget the underscore! 

    // Form header
    $mform->addElement('header', 'mainheader','<span style="font-size:22px">'.get_string('courserequestform','block_usp_mcrs'). '</span>');

    // Course Code field. 
    $coursecodearray = array();
    $coursecodearray[0] = get_string('choosecoursecode', 'block_usp_mcrs');
    $allcoursecodes = $DB->get_records_select('block_usp_mcrs_courses', 'id > 0', array(), 'id', 'id, course_code');
    foreach ($allcoursecodes as $id => $coursecodeobject) {
        $coursecodearray[$id] = $coursecodeobject->course_code;
    }
    $coursecode = $mform->addElement('select', 'coursecode', get_string('coursecode', 'block_usp_mcrs'), $coursecodearray);
    $mform->addRule('coursecode', get_string('required'), 'required', null, 'client');
    $mform->setType('coursecode', PARAM_RAW);

    // Course Name field. TODO: Course Name to pick automatically after entering Course Code
    $coursenamearray = array();
    $coursenamearray[0] = get_string('choosecoursename', 'block_usp_mcrs');
    $allcoursenames = $DB->get_records_select('block_usp_mcrs_courses', 'id > 0', array(), 'id', 'id, course_name');
    foreach ($allcoursenames as $id => $coursenameobject) {
        $coursenamearray[$id] = $coursenameobject->course_name;
    }
    $mform->addElement('select', 'coursename', get_string('coursename', 'block_usp_mcrs'), $coursenamearray);
    $mform->addRule('coursename', get_string('required'), 'required', null, 'client');
    $mform->setType('coursename', PARAM_RAW);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to achieve this using javascript, as Moodle has no functionality to fill data in a nested way.

Add AMD module js file where you are calling your mform for display purpose.

In the file where you render your mform

```
$mform->render();
```

add below line to call you amd js file.

```
$PAGE->requires->js_call_amd('local_acestructure/registration', 'init');
```

In your amd js file make httprequest / ajax call to fetch data based on your course_code select drop down change.

Thank you.